# z3 activate expression when conditions are met

Tags: python, z3

Suppose I have constraints: `[x > 2, y > 1, x < 10]`, and I want to add condition `x%4 == 0` when `y==1`, and get all results, how would I do that in Z3?

I've add blocking constraint for solved result and iterate it to get all possible SAT result, but I found out that it'll simply ignore value `y == 1`.

Below is the code that I used to test, where it yield no solution.

```py
>>> x, y = Ints('x y')
>>> x = If(y == 1, x%4==0, x)
>>> F = [x > 2, y == 1, x < 10]
>>> solve(F)
no solution
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use logical implication:

```
Implies(y == 1, (x % 4) == 0)
```

This is semantically equivalent to @Axel Kemper's answer, but I believe is more direct logically and doesn't need the `else` clause. (It also restricts the `then` branch to be a boolean, providing a bit more type-safety. This is important in a language like Python where everything is dynamically typed.)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
from z3 import *

x, y = Ints('x y') 

s = Solver()

s.add(x > 2, y == 1, x < 10)
s.add(If(y == 1, (x % 4) == 0, True))

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

For `y == 1` the constraint is fulfilled, if `(x % 4) == 0`.
Otherwise, the constraint is fulfilled anyhow.